# How to code Unsuccessful, Failed results in Great_Expectations

Tags: python, pyspark, great-expectations

I am evaluating Great Expectations to do some Data Cleaning.

I have managed to get most of code working for our needs. I am having a problem with the Attribute needed to code for unsuccessful results. For example, the following code will print "Successful" if the 'validation_results' are success

```
if validation_results["success"]:
    print ("Successful")
```

But I don't know what attribute to use for failed results.

I have tried the following:

```
if validation_results["failure"]:
    print ("Failed")

if validation_results["unsuccessful"]:
    print ("Failed")

if validation_results["false"]:
    print ("Failed")
```

But I get the error message:  object has no attribute for each of the failure attempts above.

Does anyone know what attribute will give me a failure output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check whether a key is exists in the dictionary or not. When you call a key that didn't exists, it will return an error. But you can check is the key is in the dict using this approach.

```
if "success" in validation_results:
    print ("Successful")

if "failure" in validation_results:
    print ("Failed")

if "unsuccessful" in validation_results:
    print ("Failed")

if "false" in validation_results:
    print ("Failed")
```

This is not best practice. It will be better to create a `"status"` key in the dict that contain `success`, `failure`, `unsuccessful`, or `false`

Comment: Riz, I understand what you're saying but there is an inbuilt attribute that can be used, but I don't know what it is